# Pages URI not saving in EE3

Tags: ee3, pages

I just installed my first EE3 site (EE 3.4.1), and the Pages URI entries are not saving. The page entry itself saves, but not the URI. Has anyone else experienced this or have a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I uninstalled and reinstalled the Pages module, and that fixed it.

Comment: Can this be done without losing the entries?